# How to properly proxy redis behind HAProxy?

Tags: haproxy, redis

I am configuring HAproxy and would love using with Redis, my configuration is fairly simple:

```
global
    maxconn 50000

defaults
    timeout connect 10s
    timeout client 30s
    timeout server 30s
    log global
    mode http
    option httplog
    maxconn 3000

frontend redis
    log /dev/log local0 debug
    mode tcp

    bind *:7899
    default_backend redis_servers

backend redis_servers
    server r01 xxx:7899
```

but when I try to connect to the address with the CLI:

```
redis-cli -h loadbalancer.test.app -p 7899
```

I get this log:

```
Jul 18 15:19:24 lb01 haproxy[114128]: 217.XXX.XX.XXX:279XX [18/Jul/2022:15:19:24.426] redis redis/<NOSRV> -1/-1/0 0 PR 1/1/0/0/0 0/0
```

I verified and the redis server is working properly, if I execute the same command to connect to it, but with the ip of the machine directly, I can use it with success.

Anyone can help me understand what I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your defaults section, the mode is `http`, same mode is used by your backend.
You either need to change mode in your defaults section from `http` to `tcp` or explicitly add the mode as `tcp` under backend as the redis used tcp.